# Is it possible to use MediaPipe or Openpose for pose recognition with Java?

Tags: python, java, mediapipe, openpose, teachable-machine

I would like to make a fitness-based game that uses pose recognition to distinguish between movements such as standing still, jumping jacks, running, etc. Originally I started to create this program using Google's Teachable Machine software to distinguish between my poses.

However, Teachable Machine is having a hard time doing that for fullbody poses. I believe it is because Teachable Machine is struggling to track my legs in particular - it always thinks they are on the floor even if they are lifted high. It's estimations are just inconsistant, despite me recording a variety of data.

I wanted to use another software such as Mediapipe or Openpose instead, however both of those use Python and do not use Java. I know a little bit of Python but not as strong as Java, so I was wondering if I could use python simply for the pose distinguishing and use Java for the rest of the fitness game, however I do not know how I would connect them together.